# C Error when creating an empty stack

Tags: c, stack, malloc

I'm trying to create an empty stack but somehow there is an error with the malloc I couldn't figure out even with debbuger.

The message my debbuger shows is:

```
sysmalloc: Assertion (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0) failed.
Aborted
```

How should I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
}Pixel;

typedef int TypeKey;

typedef struct {
    TypeKey Key;
    Pixel P;
} TypeItem;

typedef struct Cell_str *Pointer;

typedef struct Cell_str {
    TypeItem Item;
    Pointer Next;
} Cell;

typedef struct {
    Pointer Top, Bottom;
    int Size;
} TypeStack;

void FEmpty(TypeStack *Stack)
{
    Stack->Top = (Pointer)malloc(sizeof(Cell*));
    Stack->Bottom = Stack->Top;
    Stack->Top->Next = NULL;
    Stack->Size = 0;
}

int Empty(const TypeStack *Stack){
    return (Stack->Top == Stack->Bottom);
}

int size(TypeStack Stack)
{
    return (Stack.Size) ;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    Pixel P[500][500];; 


    TypeStack *Stack;
    FEmpty(Stack);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you cut back on the `typedef`s, and *never* hide a pointer behind a typedef - it makes for incomprehensible code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1

```
TypeStack *Stack;
FEmpty(Stack);
```

`Stack` is uninitialized - it points to nothing, or garbage.

In `FEmpty` you immediately dereference the (invalid) pointer, causing undefined behavior.

You need to either allocate the structure using `malloc`, or simply declare a local variable:

```
TypeStack Stack;
FEmpty(&Stack);
```

---

## 2

```
Stack->Top = (Pointer)malloc(sizeof(Cell*));
```

Next, you don't allocate enough memory here. You're only allocating the size of the *pointer itself*, and not the structure it points to.

Use this construct to avoid this mistake. [And don't cast the result of `malloc`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

```
Stack->Top = malloc(sizeof(*Stack->Top));
```